# Retrieve the failed connection reason from NEVPNManager?

Tags: ios, vpn, ios-app-extension, networkextension

I'm trying to establish an `IKEv2` connection on iOS using the `NEVPNManager`.

I update my profile successfully using `NEVPNProtocolIKEv2` and start the connection process but after a few seconds the connection stops without any error.

Is there any way I can get more information about the connection to see why it failed? There does not appear to be anything helpful in the `NEVPNManager` object.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnconnection?language=objc

Comment: Hello Friend, do you get any resolve for this, i'm facing issue to establish connection for first time.